# Echo the Requested URL in PHP

Tags: php

I am not even A PHP newbie. But I need to call BS on a outside consultant who has come to my company and told me something was impossible.

Is it possible in PHP to simply create a webpage that displays the URL requested by the user.

In other words: rather than echoing/Printing   "Hello World"

I would like the page to print the URL that the user requested.

Comment: Uh, yeah kinda.  Start with PHP_SELF and then add GET.  You won't get the #fragment and you won't get any rerouting, so depends upon how pedantic this consultant is being.

Comment: You can get #hashes with REQUEST_URI

Comment: @rm-vanda: Uhm, [are you sure about that](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25804)?

Comment: hmm That seems a little basic for a "consultant"

Comment: Using @rm-vanda solution I seem to get `index` on a wordpress site of mine. Using @ianP solution I get `/`. Also if I do a 301 redirect, I will never be able to see the original requested URL.

Comment: @bishop is right. You can't --- I was working with facebook one time, and they leave a # in their redirect uri - so that's where I got that faulty idea.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat - I edited my answer for a (very) simple solution to that --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Comment: Yes.  I figured. Thank you very much. I have to wait seven more minutes however before I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks again you have probably ruined some corporate posers day

Comment: Ah, but PHP_SELF only gives you the name of the script -- not the directory the script is in - plus, if you have fancy rerouting, PHP_SELF will not even appear in the URL requested by the user.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with:

`echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`--

for a full list:

`print_r($_SERVER)`

Another useful one is `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

If you're going to do a redirect, you have more footwork to do, but a straightforward solution would be:

`header("Location: {$site}?original_request={$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");` - and then handle the rest in the page you redirect to.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the `full` url. This can be done with.

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo $url;
```

Just incase the port is included.

```
$port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: Missing port, in the event such port is in the URL.

Comment: @bishop, that should help.

Comment: Yep.  But...the PHP code doesn't know if the port was actually present in the request or if its just the default one.  So if the consultant means "always exactly the same", then the URl can't be built reliably.

Comment: @bishop this wasn't meant for robustness :). Just an example and he just wanted to know if it can be done. It can also be checked for ssl etc but I think he just wanted to prove it can be displayed some how.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, both you and the consultant are correct.  In most cases, yes you can get the exact URL.  In many cases, the URL will be approximate.  In some cases, you might not get anywhere close to the requested URL.

Here are some barriers to building the *exact* URL:

1. The #fragment isn't sent
2. You don't know if :port was present (so you can't know whether to add it or not)
3. You don't know what outside PHP rerouting was done (eg in .htaccess)

You could get around these by having a hidden input variable that is filled by Javascript with the full URL, which is then posted.  But then the argument is "well what if Javascript isn't turned on."

So, I'd say "yes you can" is the practical/pragmatic answer, while "no you can't" is the academic answer.